# Check most current RPI-Firmware available from Git Repo?

Tags: pi-3, firmware, git, rpi-update, version-control

I'm trying to to retrieve most recent master version from the [Hexxeh/rpi-firmware](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware) which is used by Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

The `rpi-update` update script exist on [this page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update) but I'm unable to fishout how they check if their version is newer than my local one.

What repo file, or what CLI/Bash command cold I use to get the newest available version online?

**EDIT:**

I could do `sudo JUST_CHECK=1 rpi-update` but is there cleaner way?

Comment: They don't. It uses `git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough idea how I could achieve this due to the fact that the author states the kernel 'bump to' on commit comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib, json

json_url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits'
json_response = urllib.urlopen(json_url)
json_data = json.loads(json_response.read())

count = 0
for json_entry in json_data:
    count += 1

    for property, content in json_entry.iteritems():
        if property == 'commit' and isinstance(content, dict):
            if content['message'].find("Bump to") != -1:
                print count, ": " , property, ": ", content['message'][0:22]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `/boot/.firmware_revision` file created by the installation process.

The following bash script (extracted from Hexxeh's actual rpi-update script) could be used to extract the required info:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit

REPO_URI=${REPO_URI:-"https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware"}

BRANCH=${BRANCH:-"master"}
ROOT_PATH=${ROOT_PATH:-"/"}
BOOT_PATH=${BOOT_PATH:-"/boot"}
FW_PATH="${BOOT_PATH}"
FW_REV=${1:-""}
FW_REVFILE="${FW_PATH}/.firmware_revision"

# ask github for latest version hash
REPO_API=${REPO_URI/github.com/api.github.com\/repos}/git/refs/heads/${BRANCH}
FW_REV=$(curl -Ls ${REPO_API} | awk '{ if ($1 == "\"sha\":") { print substr($2, 2, 40) } }')
if [[ "${FW_REV}" == "" ]]; then
        echo " *** No hash received from github: ${REPO_API}"
        # run again with errors not suppressed
        curl -L ${REPO_API}
        exit 1
else
        echo "latest version: $FW_REV"
fi

# display local version hash
if [ -f "$FW_REVFILE" ]; then
        LOCAL_HASH=$(cat "$FW_REVFILE")
        echo " local version: $LOCAL_HASH"
else
        LOCAL_HASH=0
        echo " local version: unkown"
fi
```

Comment: this gives you a version which is installed, not the most recent version that is available for download. Also, without first running rpi-upgrade, this file does not exist.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example script (containing a subset of the lines of Hexxeh's rpi-update script) to display the required information.

Comment: This is what I've been looking at. As the code points, I have run the CURL for the Github subversion API which gives me some information. The HEXX repo does specify the version number in their commit descriptions pretty much every time so this is what I'll be using.

Comment: Which of the two answers is what you've been looking for? From your comment it looks like **this** answer, however you have accepted the **other** answer as the best one...

Comment: Well, you just pasted piece of code letting me know 'might be somewhere there'. And you pointed out things I have already knew and prior to your answer was already scripting the answer.

Comment: Well, in fact the _piece of code_ is a complete bash script, the contents of which I extracted (specially for you) from Hexxeh's script. If you copy the _piece of code_ and put it in a new script file, e.g. named **get-rpi-hash.sh**, and make the file executable, then running it will display both the hash of the official repository **and** the hash of the locally installed version (or _unknown_ if it is not yet installed). I believe that is what you asked for, or?

Comment: Still awaiting your comment on the _piece of code_ ...